# Homebrew Replaced MySQL

Tags: macos, homebrew, mysql

I had mysql running fine on OS X until I accidentally installed it via homebrew as well. I cant start mysql using preference pane and I cant login to phpmyadmin using my root password. Is there anything i can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest uninstalling all occurrences of MySQL and reinstalling using just one method :).

I've seen some useful posts across Stack Exchange that explain how to remove MySQL, like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16150484/756329). Hopefully that can get you on the right path.